# How do I remove the annoying scrollbar in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

Please see this example:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

I am inside Firefox. Please click on "Loading Data" -> "JSON Data". Once you see the example, please press `Ctrl -` so that the resolution changes and you will see the annoying horizontal scrollbar in jqGrid. How do I prevent this scrollbar?

Answer (score -1):

try giving width as 101%.

```
<div class="ui-jqgrid-bdiv" style="height: auto; width: 101%; ">
```

Comment: That doesn't work. 101% might differ. If I have a big scrollbar it doesn't work so this isn't a great solution.